# How can I use a new reader instance in ever job instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

When I launch two jobs at the same time, it seems as though the same reader object is being used across different jobs. This is problematic because we are conserving some information about the whole job in the reader.

Here is an example of how everything is set up:

```
@Bean(name = "MyJob")
public Job job(Step myStep) { create job and return it }

@Bean
public Step myStep(
        @Qualifier("myReader") ItemReader<Object> reader,
        @Qualifier("myWriter") ItemWriter<Object> writer) 
{ create step and return it }

@Bean
public ItemReader<Object> myReader(
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) { returns new MyReaderObject }
```

`MyReaderObject` itself also has @StepScope. Is there something missing? What can I do so that every job instance will have its own reader object?

Comment: Are you sharing spring-configuration across these batches? How do you start off a batch job - using a scheduler? Some details and config might help.
Tho different spring batch jobs should not interfere with each other - two batches interfering does not sound typical at all

Comment: Hi @SaifuddinMerchant, thanks for the input! Yes, they do share configuration. They are started off using a JMS listener which receives messages from a Queue and launched using a JobLauncher's (obtained with JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);) run method.

Comment: How do you differentiate between two different jobs? The above line seems to indicate that you are running the same job.

Comment: Please share your code/configurations for us to be able to better diagnose the issue.

Comment: I've edited the question with some code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So your scope for your reader is `@StepScope` (i.e. one per step), but you want multiple concurrent invocations of a step to use different instances?  Have you tried `@JobScope`?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/JobScope.html